# How to select and copy data from cell D6 and only the visible data from a filtered table with a range D13 to D9999 using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, copy

I am trying to create a button that will filter a table, select and copy data from cell D6 and only the visible data from a filtered table with a range D13 to D9999 to the clipboard so that I can use the information to paste it anywhere else such as Word, notepad, one note, etc using CTRL+V. I have written this code but nothing gets pasted when I go CTRL+V. I think it has to do with the un-filtering that I do in the end. But that is important. How do I get this working?

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Cost")
ws.Range("D13:D9999").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
Range("D6","D13:D9999").Select
Selection.COPY
ws.Range("D13:D9999").AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Been researching it for a while But I can't seem to find anything that will work. Thanks.

Comment: I am afraid that it is not possible to paste a range in Notepad. Even in Word, if it is a discontinuous one, not so simple...

Answer (score 0):

Qucik and dirty solution is to

- remove the `AutoFilter` at the end. Infact, make sure that `.Copy` is the last command in the code - this action will keep the `Application.CutCopyMode` which retains the copied text in clipboard until further action.
- And only copy a single Range i.e., remove `D6` from copy.

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Cost")
ws.Range("D13:D9999").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
Range("D13:D9999").Select
Selection.Copy

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the visible cells only after applying the filter, something like the following: *(note I avoid using Select)*

```
Set r1 = [d6]

'filter the range
Set r2 = Range("d10:d20")

r2.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor

Range(r1, r2.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)).Copy
```

You'll then have to execute your Paste **before** you turn off the autofilter.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can get this done using one button or does it have to be two buttons. One for copying and the other for un-filtering? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Excellent I don't know of any way for Excel to know when you have executed your `control v` operation. So no, if that's what you were doing, two buttons.